# Are questions about historic interpretations on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions about historic interpretations or how specific people from history applied the field of hermeneutics to their work on topic?

I have tested the waters a little here: [How consistent were Augustine's hermeneutics?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/75/36)

Answer (score 14):

I personally think that they're very on topic.

How we understand and interpret the Bible has changed throughout history.  Things that we have understood in the past we have corrected and modified throughout history.  It's this history of hermeneutics and exegesis that has built the foundation of where we are today.

So, as long as the questions relate to translating and interpreting the text (even historical translation and interpretation methods), I think they're completely on topic.

Comment: I agree. (Allso, the idea in your middle paragraph should probably be one of the points of several that need to be made here: [What is "Regula Fidei"?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/78)

Comment: Also many things that we think we understand now in the present, are really just devolutions from the things that were known in the past.  While some knowledge has built up, some has been lost.