# Defining site tag use and refinement: Context tag

Tags: discussion

For a summary of issues that engendered this question, see [its initial sister question](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3424/2070).

### This question is about the [context](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/context) tag.

Currently our site tag summary for [context](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/context) is:

> The immediate literary setting in which a text appears.

The extended description is:

> *Context* is the broad literary setting in which a given smaller text appears. It is sometimes distinguished from the *co-text*, a more specialist term for the immediate literary setting of a given text. In text and language analysis, "context" is especially associated with the concept of "[pragmatics](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pragmatics/)",
>
> > Pragmatics is sometimes characterized as dealing with the effects of *context*. This is equivalent to saying it deals with utterances, if one collectively refers to all the facts that can vary from utterance to utterance as ‘context.’
>
> Questions with this tag will focus on the nature of the context of the specified text, and the constraints it places on the understanding of that text.

[As its sister question summary of issues reveals](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3424/2070), most textual questions could be tagged [context](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/context).  **But if most could be tagged so, what *specific* parameters make a question actually worthy of having this tag applied?**

Comment: Perhaps we need to get rid of the context tag and specify the *type* of context: Eg, historical-context and literary-context (are there more types of context?)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, as noted by James Shewey in [a comment](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3425/defining-site-tag-use-and-refinement-context-tag#comment5690_3425), there are different types of contexts.

- Since we already have a [history](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag, the [context](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/context) tag should *not* be used for historical context (in fact, [historical-context](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-context) could even be made into a tag synonym for [history](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history)).
- We also already have a [cultural-analysis](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cultural-analysis) tag, so it should not overlap with this (although a historical culture is arguably covered by [history](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) also).
- Because we already have the following tags, the [context](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/context) tag would either need to be declared as synonymous with these or clearly distinguished (they actually have [a hyper-/hyponymous relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy_and_hypernymy), which is not *technically* synonymous).:

  - [literary-genre](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literary-genre)
  - [literary-structure](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literary-structure)
  - [literary-device](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literary-device) (you could argue that [context](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/context) *is* a literary device).

I think this easily becomes way too complicated and will inevitably lead to more confusion and frustration for new users as to when to use this tag over others.

**I propose [burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120640/166644) of the [context](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/context) tag.**

Comment: I think tagging questions about extra-biblical writings using the history tag is a great idea, but if we do this, then the context tag should *not* be synonymous. The reason being, there is also [cultural context](https://www.amazon.com/Social-Sciences-New-Testament-Interpretation/dp/0801047587) which uses anthropology and archeology and literary context (the context of a passage *within* the manuscript) neither of which necessarily involve other historical writings.

Comment: But I too vote for burnination of the context tag!

Comment: @JamesShewey I think we should keep tags such as [tag:literary-genre], [tag:literary-structure], and [tag:cultural-analysis], which I believe adequately address these.

Comment: @JamesShewey I don't see why we need a tag at all for *internal* context of a text. That's like tagging every question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) with [tag:programming-language] - it's implied and adds no value for finding questions by tags. Every answer about a text should consider its internal context where relevant.

Comment: What about a question that specifically asks about the literary "context" of a passage? One might ask a question such as "Why does X writer use Y terms in other places, but Z term here?" That is not a genre or a structure question, but maybe [tag:grammar]. But since you note the "a hyper-/hyponymous" relation of "context" to these other tags, maybe it would be useful to **only allow the context tag on questions that have particular tags also applied.** The value of that would be that if one were doing a "contextual" study of a passage, one only need search "context" (not every subtag of it).

Comment: @ScottS The computer scientist in me is screaming "NOOO!!" The correct way to handle that would **not** be to have multiple tags (again, it will be too confusing for new users and isn't sustainable), but rather to prefix tags names with some common search element. So context-genre, context-structure, etc. That way context-* finds them all. To illustrate this, type `[literary-*]` into the search bar on the main BH.SE site.

Comment: Okay, so are you proposing that we consider changing "literary-genre" to "context-genre," et al.? And maybe even "cultural-analysis" to "context-cultural"? My point was more that somehow all "contextual" questions could be searched easily, which your point about `[X-*]` makes sense (though some non-programming users may not find that intuitive).

Comment: After reading ScottS's three questions, this tag stood out to me as too broad to be helpful. Agree on burnination.

Comment: @ScottS no, I'm proposing we just burninate this tag and stop using it. But I wanted to point out there is a better way to find things by tag than requiring two tags (there is no way to make a tag dependent on another and thus it would be unenforceable and quickly unmanageable).

Comment: I think it would be better to make history a synonym of historical-context, and to add other history-based tags as needed.

Comment: @Dan Literary-context is definitely valuable in some places, because it's often ignored by exegetes. Proverbs, parables, psalms - they're all frequently considered in isolation, and it's fair for wanting a tag for questions explicitly after a contextually-informed interpretation.

Comment: Another type of context would be canonical-context.

Comment: @curiousdannii see my comments above. Specifically, if we are keeping those tags, it may make sense to frontload context- in the name so we can easily find those tags. As an example, go to the main site and search for [literary-*]